Sum with GROUP BY on recordset cloned from form VBA
I've got an Access form in a subform that can be filtered with three different filters (for Date, Status and Region) on the main form.
In the footer of the subform, there's a textbox that calculates the sum of a column in the subform, according to the filters, if they're active.
My intent is to calculate the sum of that column, GROUPING BY another column of the same form.
How can I do it? I've tried creating a Recordset.Clone of the subform when a filter is activated, but I don't know how to calculate the query
SELECT SUM([Column1]) FROM rs GROUP BY [Column2]

and put the result in the textbox.
Thanks for the help.
Here's a screenshot of my form:

As you can see, [Column1] called "Numero" contains some repeated values. My intent is to put inside the textbox in the right-bottom part of the form, the sum of [Column2] which is "Valore merce", grouped by [Column1]. So the correct sum would be 4551€. This sum should change according to the filters in the main form.

Thanks to everyone, I found a solution.
I created another query, equal to subform's one except for the fact that I removed Column1. Then, I created another small subform with only a textbox that contains sum of Column2. Finally, I modified the code in order to apply the same filter of the subform also to this new small subform. It perfectly works.

A "Group By" indicates multiple summed values, but only one can shown in a textbox. Don't you mean to filter on Column2?

Can you show the schema of your tables, some sample data and the results you would prefer to have?

@LajosArpad of  course, just posted. Thank you.

Thanks @LajosArpad, but my problem is how to put the result of the query, which must take into account the filters in the form, into the textbox

@Matilde so far the only code you have given is the query. I have improved the query. Have you tested the improved query? Is the result correct? If so, then please proceed and apply it for your textbox.

So, you have duplicated dates and you want to count them exactly once into your sum. So you will need to aggregate the fields into an average and then aggregate that too:
select sum(tempval)
from
(
    select avg([Column2]) as tempval
    from rs
    group by [Column1]
) t


Great idea but, sadly, Access SQL cannot aggregate an aggregate. You must use a subquery.

@Gustav thanks for pointing that out. I have modified my answer accordingly. I presumed that aggregation of aggregation is possible in Access. Apparently it was premature to presume this. Thanks again!
